# how can I translate the subject like "www.freebase.com/m/0cz9079" into words that can be read by human beings?

Tags: rdf, freebase

Now I get freebase-FB2M.txt in the SimpleQuestion dataset like the picture below, how can I translate the subject like `www.freebase.com/m/0cz9079` into words that can be read by human beings?

[image]

In more detail, how can i get the exact meaning of "www.freebase.com/m/0cz9079"?

Comment: BTW, this is [Turgut Doğan Şahin](http://dbpedia.org/page/Turgut_Do%C4%9Fan_%C5%9Eahin). HTH.

Comment: thank you. but how do you know that?

Comment: Ask [DBpedia](https://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=SELECT+*+WHERE+%7B%3Fs+owl%3AsameAs+freebase%3Am.0cz9079+.+%3Fs+rdfs%3Alabel+%3Flabel+.+FILTER+%28lang%28%3Flabel%29%3D%22en%22%29%7D&format=text%2Fhtml) or [Wikidata](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20*%20WHERE%20%7B%3Fs%20wdt%3AP646%20%22%2Fm%2F0cz9079%22%20.%20%3Fs%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Flabel%20.%20FILTER%20(lang(%3Flabel)%3D%22en%22)%7D)

Comment: I really appreciate your help.You let me know how to query the meaning of a line, but i need to translate the whole document. Should I write a script and then post my query request to this site? Do you know other simple ways? Thank you again.

Comment: I do not know where one can find `rdfs:label` or something like for all Freebase entities. Probably searching questions with the [tag:freebase] tag would be helpful. Also you can answer you question on https://opendata.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The moral equivalent to rdfs:label in Freebase-speak is /type/object/name. It won't give you the "exact meaning" but at least its name.

If you want a more well rounded view of a particular object/topic, you probably want to take a holistic view of its name(s) (in various languages), its types, and its properties.

BTW, I'm pretty familiar with the Freebase data dumps and don't recognize freebase-FB2M.txt so I suspect that was produced by some third party, not the Freebase team.